# Counting how many times byte overflow in Java

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I have some problems with my for loop.

I am trying to count how many times does byte overflow in some limits , but i am not sure how should i reset the value of byte and how can i make the for looping work, because now has problem , which i can't find:

```
  public class OverflowedByte {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int limit = scan.nextInt();
    int countOverflows = 0;
    for (byte i = -128; i < limit; i++) {           
        if (i == Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
            countOverflows++;
            i = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
            System.out.println(countOverflows);    
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- You are **resetting** your loop counter value. So it never reaches the limit!
- And even if you would not do that: your **limit** is an int; not a byte. So a **byte** counter will *overrun* (!) before reaching that limit (if the limit is larger than Byte.MAX_VALUE)!

Thus: you have to work with an "int" counter for your loop; and a byte value for the overflow checking:

```
 for (int i=0, j = -128; i < limit; i++, j++) {
    if (j == Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
        countOverflows++;
        j = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println(countOverflows);
    }
```